# Injections and query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-injection

I made a class that connects to my DB and inserts some values. Is it secure or how can I protect this further from injections? The object declaration will come from variables with POST from a form, after being validated, ofc. Just want to know if this is secure.

That, and also, should I make a method for every query I need? Or is there a better and secure way?

```
<?php
include "db/db_info.php";
/*$DBServer
$DBUser
$DBPass
$DBName*/
class WorkDB {
    private $server;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $name;
    private $conn;

    public function __construct( $server, $user, $pass, $name ) {
        $this->server=$server;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->pass=$pass;
        $this->name=$name;
    }

    public function tryconn() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli(  $this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name );

    if ( mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die( '*************Connection Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno()  . '):'
                .mysqli_connect_error() );
    }


    else echo 'ok';

}

public function query_register( $user, $pass, $email ) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?,?)" );
    $stmt->bind_param( "sss", $user, $pass, $email );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}


}//end of class


$a=new WorkDB( $DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName );
$a->tryconn();
$a->query_register( 'a', 'b', 'c' );


?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What you did well

- Storing sensitive information, such as the database connection parameters, separately from the source code is a good idea.
- You used parameterized queries with placeholders, which are not vulnerable to SQL injection.

#### Things to work on

- Your indentation is inconsistent.
- `tryconn()` should not `echo 'ok'` on success, as that pollutes the output.
- `$a` is a horrible name for your database handle.  It's conventionally called `$db` or something like that.

Comment: The echo'ok' was just for testing purposes. But where should I put my queries? each in every method? And should I make a method that checks if the Sesion id is set?

Answer (score 6):

1. I think `tryconn()` could use a better name. Perhaps just
   `connect()`.
2. Avoid using the `die` function in you code. Consider learning about the different types of [exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) (maybe implement an [SPL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php)) and throw an exception instead.
3. As 200_success said, keep the view (the `echo`) out of your model class. Larger projects may require you to keep things [separated](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/).
4. Look at your names here: `WorkDB`, `tryconn`, and `query_register`. Try and apply some sort of consistency to your code. Find a style that suits you and the project and stick to it. [Here's one](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html) to get you started.
5. `query_register()` has very limited functionality. Either make the class more specific, so that it only handles CRUD operations for users, or generalize it more, so that it's more of a query builder class.
6. Comments such as `//end of class` do not really help the reader. In code where readers may have a hard time figuring out what a section does (algorithms, complex sequences, obscure functions, large functions, etc.) then comments are fantastic. If comments are just thrown in willy-nilly, then they're useless.
7. `$a=new WorkDB` could use some breathing space around the assignment. Again, consistency and legibility are important.
8. Lastly, as 200_success stated, `$a` is a pretty bad name for a variable. Again, find a coding style and stick to it. Many would say that variables should have some sort of meaning to their name.